# Как разметить игровое поле Android?

Tags: android, java

Как правильно разметить игровое поле, или как это обычно делается. И как эту разметку связать с кодом. Необходимо, чтобы внизу экрана были кнопки, вверху вспомогательная информация, посредине игровой процесс. Возможно легче объяснить правильно, чем пытаться исправить то, что уже есть.

Это мое первое игроровое приложение. Я пытался сделать разметку таким образом:

1. Верхняя панель - `LinearLayout`.
2. Посредине игровое поле. Оно представляет собой класс `Round`, который расширяет `LinearLayout`. В нем будет происходить основная прорисовка приложения.
3. Внизу панель с кнопками - `LinearLayout`.
   Класс `GameProcessView` расширяет `LinearLayout`, он отвечает за периодическую перерисовку.

Начали возникать некоторые проблемы:
В классе Round мне необходимо получать его границы, но они все равны нулям (если получать их в конструкторе). Проблема казалось бы решена, когда я перегрузил метод `onSizeChanged(...)`, но при рисовании в полученных границах(я их проверил, они правильные) ничего не отображается. Если же в конструкторе написать:

```
setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
```

То прорисовка происходит, но как и следовало ожидать, закрашивается фоновый рисунок.

```
<com.pos.GameProcessView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gameView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/game_wall_paper"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topPanel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<com.pos.Round
    android:id="@+id/gameField"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.28"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</com.pos.Round>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomPanel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center|clip_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/var1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/square"
        android:background="@color/buttonBackground">
    <requestFocus />
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/var2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/square"
        android:background="@color/buttonBackground">
    </ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
</com.pos.GameProcessView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое вообще-то делается кодом, а не .xml шаблоном. Тут тебе нужно вызывать ItemMenu из нажатия на кнопку Menu.

[Про размещение объектов на экране](http://dajver.blogspot.com/2012/01/android-1-surfaceview.html) и как делается меню [вот тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/menu.php)

Answer (score 1):

Для создания игр лучше прочитать книгу Марио Цехнер - Программирование игр для Android, в ней достотчно хорошо рассказано как сделать простой движок, и написать простую 2Д игру с наложением информации\кнопок на игровое поле (то что вас интересует, а главное поймете как это делается) + доработка движка для написания 3Д игры